# Question about complex linear functionals

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

There is a proposition at Folland's Real Analysis as below:

**Proposition.** If $u$ is a real functional on $X$ and $f:X \to \mathbb{C}$ is defined by $f(x)=u(x)-iu(ix)$ then $f$ is complex linear. In this case, if $X$ is normed, we have $||u||=||f||$.

It is clear that we have  $||u|| \le ||f||$. The book proves the other part by using sign function but I do not understand how do we conclude the result. So, how do you prove the  $||f|| \le ||u||$ part?

Comment: I think you mean $f(x)=u(x)-iu(ix)$.

Comment: Yes, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider at a non-zero vector $x$, lets look at $u(e^{i\varphi}x)$. Since $u$ is continuous, real valued and you have $u(e^{i(\varphi+\pi) }x)=u(-e^{i\varphi}x)=-u(e^{i\varphi}x)$ the function $\varphi\mapsto u(e^{i\varphi}x)$ must intersect zero.

Let $x':= e^{i\varphi} x$ be so that $u(x')=0$.  Note that $\|x'\|=\|x\|$.

With $u(x')=0$ you've got
$$-iu(ix')=u(x')-iu(ix'-)=f(x')=f(e^{i\varphi}x)=e^{i\varphi}f(x).$$
It follows $\frac{|f(x)|}{\|x\|}=\frac{|u(ix')|}{\|x'\|}$. So 
$$\sup_{x\neq0}\frac{|f(x)|}{\|x\|}≤\sup_{x\neq0}\frac{|u(x)|}{\|x\|}$$